# python regex not detecting square brackets

Tags: python, regex

I have a scenario where I want to remove all special characters except spaces from given content and I am working with Python and I was using this regex

```
re.sub(r"[^a-zA-z0-9 ]+","",content)
```

Itt was removing all special characters but was not removing square brackets `[ ]` and I just don't know why this happening??

after that I just use this regex

```
content = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-z0-9 ]+|\[|\]","",content)
```

It's working flawlessly in `IDLE IDE` and removing all kind of special characters but when I want to replace large files like Wikipedia's page then its now not removing closing square brackets `]` I just dont why `Python` doing this weird behavior and

Comment: Even with the lowercase `z` your code should be removing closing square brackets. I tried it and it removes them for me. Can you show the output where it's not removing the  closing square brackets?

Comment: @JoeR `[A-z]` == `[A-Z\[\\\]\^_\`a-z]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a lowercase `z` where it should be upppercase. Change:

```
re.sub(r"[^a-zA-z0-9 ]+","",content)
```

to:

```
re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+","",content)
```

---

For the record, the range `'A-z'` expanded to the characters `A...Z`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, ``` `` ```, `a...z`; that's why your regex was removing everything but those chars.

ASCII table:

[image]